# complex numbers in binomial function form

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem

Is it possible to rewrite $f(z) = z^{n}(z^*)^{m}$ with the use of the binomial function.

The binomial function is defined as $(x+y)^{n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k}y^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{k}y^{n-k}$

For the equation $f(z) = z^{n}(z^*)^{m}= (x+iy)^{n}(x-iy)^{m}$

[lets call $(x+iy)^{n}$ term 1 and $(x-iy)^{m}$ term 2]

we get:

$ 1: \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{k}iy^{n-k}$

$ 2: \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} x^{k}(-i)y^{m-k}$

the reason why i want to rewrite f(z) is to show that f(z) is not anylical in any point, but am not sure how to draw this conclusion from here.

any help on how i should approach this? And is the binomial function applied correctly?

thanx

added Cauchy-Riemann approach as advised by David:

$f(z) = z^{n}(z^*)^{m}$

write in polar form:

$f(z) = (e^{i\theta})^{n}(e^{-i\theta})^{m} = e^{i\theta n} e^{-i \theta m}$

$f(z) = (cos(\theta n) +i sin(\theta n))(cos(\theta m) -i sin(\theta m)) = cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m) + icos(\theta n)sin(\theta m)+ i cos(\theta m)sin(\theta n) - sin(\theta n)sin(\theta m) $

f(z) = u(n,m) + iv(n,m)

$u = cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m) - sin(\theta n)sin(\theta m) $

$v = icos(\theta n)sin(\theta m)+ i cos(\theta m)sin(\theta n) $

$u_{n} = -\theta sin(\theta n)cos(\theta m) - \theta con(\theta n)sin(\theta m)$

$u_{m} = -\theta cos(\theta n)sin(\theta m)- \theta sin(\theta n)sin(\theta m)$

$v_{n} = - i\theta sin(\theta n)sin(\theta m)+ i \theta cos(\theta m)cos(\theta n)$

$v_{m} = i\theta cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m) - i \theta sin(\theta m)sin(\theta n)$

does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann eq; not analytical.

Comment: Hint: have you studied the Cauchy-Riemann equations?  And have you learnt how to use them in polar form?  Unless you have been told you **must** use the binomial theorem, I think it would be easier to avoid it.

Comment: yes i have studied the Cauchy - Riemann equations, but only with more straightforward problems. If i use Cauchy-Riemann and polar form i also get stuck pretty early on. I will add what i did to the original question.

Comment: hmmm i think i can solve the problem the way you described advised. that sure is an easier route! i made a +/- mistake somewhere thanx

Comment: In the binomial sums, $i$ and $y$ must be raised to the same power or else put together inside parentheses like this: $(iy)^{n-k}$ and $(-iy)^{m-k}.$ Just FYI in case you need that technique in the future.